# Conexão webservice PHP ocorrendo cURL ERROR: 35

Tags: php, web-service, libcurl, soap, ssl

Olá, estou tentando realizar uma conexão a um webservice que utiliza segurança SSL , sendo necessário o uso de um certificado.
Estava tentando inicialmente em um servidor linux, mas agora estou utilizando em meu computador com windows e xampp. Já tentei a conexão com a bilbioteca NuSOAP e utilizando o SoapClient do PHP.

**O erro que esta ocorrendo é:** HTTP Error: cURL ERROR: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to

**Dados:**
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.21
CURL: 7.47.1
Biblioteca NuSOAP v 1.123

**Solução:**

Resolvi o meu problemas alterando dois pontos da minha conexão:

- Primeiramente, li em alguns lugares que poderia ser problema do certificado. O meu certificado estava com a private key e 3 certificados(begin certificate). Deixei a private key e o primeiro cerficado, removendo o restante da cadeia de certificados.
- Segundo, vi que ao realizar uma conexão SSL, a configuração de timeout do PHP pode ser ignorada, assim, é necessário informar o parâmetro "connection_timeout" ao realizar a conexão SSL.

Comment: Você pode tentar alterar as settings do **cURL SSL** para a versão 3: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);

Comment: Opa..valeu  a atenção, resolvi o problema.